# Update Android SDK sources

Tags: android, sdk

I want to install the latest build tools using `android` package. On attempting to list the Android SDK packages:

```
$ android list sdk
Refresh Sources:
  Fetching https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
  Failed to fetch URL https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, reason: File not found
  Fetched Add-ons List successfully
  Refresh Sources
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml
  Failed to fetch URL https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml, reason: File not found
Refresh Sources:
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml
  Failed to fetch URL https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml, reason: File not found
Refresh Sources:
  Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml
  Failed to fetch URL https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml, reason: File not found
Packages available for installation or update: 0
```

It seems that I need to update the sources. How can I do that?

Comment: No the source path is correct. It might be a permission issue. Try doing this: `sudo chown -R username:username ~/.android`